# A question about a proof in nonlinear programming book

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization

I have a question about the proof of Proposition 1.2.1 (Stationarity of limit points for gradient methods) in the nonlinear programming book (2nd edition) by Bertsekas. At the beginning of the proof the limit point is assumed to have a nonzero gradient, but it seems this assumption is not used in the rest of the proof. It seems even if the limit point's gradient is zero, the contradiction at the end of the proof still holds.

I post a copy of the proof below:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Can any one help? Thanks.

Comment: The goal is to show that the limit point of the descent algorithm has a zero gradient. To show by contradiction, it is first assumed that the limit point has a nonzero gradient. However, I cannot see how this assumption is used then in the proof.

Comment: oh, sorry. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I just post the copy of the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I see I missed gradient related is defined for nonstationary points.